# How to make a redirect without internet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, redirect, react-router

I have a problem that is burning my head

I have my web page created in React, and it detects when there is no internet or no conection to the Server, once this happens an action is performed, this action I want to do is redirect to my Main Page without stopping to see the interface of the site and continue operating offline the page

All of redirects of Javascript like

window.location.href / replace / assign doesn't work, i think it is because it redirect by URL and for this you need connection.

Im ussing the  of react, which is the one I currently use to make my redirects where the new location will override the current location in the history stack, this components work without internet to move inside the site, but this only works if I touch a button that is linked to this action. but what I want is for this action to be done automatically.

```
window.setInterval(function () {
  axios.get('https://roraso.herokuapp.com/User/CurrentUser',
  { headers: { 'access-token': localStorage.getItem('access-token')}})
      .then(res => {
          if(localStorage.getItem('status') === 'offline'){

            localStorage.setItem('status', 'online');
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Reconected',
                text: 'Online Mode',
                type: 'success',
            })
            return window.location.href = "/";
          }
      }) 
      .catch(err => {
          if(localStorage.getItem('status') === 'online'){

            localStorage.setItem('status', 'offline');
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'No connection detected',
                text: 'Offline Mode',
                type: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
            }).then((result) => {
              if (result.value) {
                return <Redirect to='/' />
              }
            }) 
          }
      })

}, 7000);
```

This is the piece of code that detect the connection to the server or internet too, but it doesn't work. I don't have any more idea to make this redirect work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

I solved it by exporting my class with the HOC withRouter, thats allow me to access to the history and use the redirect props.history.push ('/')

```
       checker_status(props){
          window.setInterval(function () {
              axios.get('https://roraso.herokuapp.com/User/CurrentUser',
              { headers: { 'access-token': localStorage.getItem('access-token')}})
                  .then(res => {
                      if(localStorage.getItem('status') === 'offline'){

                        localStorage.setItem('status', 'online');
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Reconected',
                            text: 'Online Mode',
                            type: 'success',
                        })
                        props.history.push('/')
                      }
                  }) 
                  .catch(err => {
                      if(localStorage.getItem('status') === 'online'){

                        localStorage.setItem('status', 'offline');
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'No connection detected',
                            text: 'Offline Mode',
                            type: 'error',
                            confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
                        }).then((result) => {
                          if (result.value) {
                            props.history.push('/')
                          }
                        }) 
                      }
                  })

            }, 7000);
        }

        componentWillMount(){
           this.checker_status(this.props);
        }

        export default withRouter(myClass);
```